# News/Update Drop Down Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've recently gotten into web programming, and I am completely overwhelmed.  I've started off with the basics, html, css, and javascript.  On my first webpage, I'm interested in implementing a drop down news section for where I post updates.  The best example I can give is the way Riot Games does it:

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/

You see, under the latest news section?  For the life of me I can't figure out where to begin implementing something such as that.  Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip that helped me a lot: download an extension called FireBug for Firefox. This add-on will allow you to right click on any element in a page and "inspect" that element - see it's source code. You can track down any CSS styles involved in styling the element and also search the included JavaScript files for an id, name, or class that was assigned to the element in which you are interested.